# Plotting very many point

Tags: plot

I have a file with aproximately 7.4 million (complex) points. These points probably from a subset of a fractal. How can these points be plotted?
I want to put them  in a postscript file, but I'm not sure if postscript can handle this many points.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you,
Noud

Answer (score 0):

Postscript seems like a poor option because it will maintain each of the points as a separate object. I think a better approach would be to use something like [ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org) command line tools to write pixels to some target image. Then you're not trying to maintain 7.4 million vector shapes -- just pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I think usual scatter plot will be OK for you. Concerning EPS/PDF -- formally it is possible, but resulting file will have a size of order of hundred Mb. I agree that bitmap image may be better for yours case.

For producing such plot you can use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net), for example. It is free (GPL) cross-platform plotting library. There is a front-end [UDAV](http://udav.sf.net) for MathGL.